# Is there any rails QR code plugin for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, qr-code

I want to generate QR code for my application which is going to run in Rails 3.0,
Is there any plugin available for that ?

Thanks in Advance,
Jak.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951188/generating-a-qr-code-in-rails

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google's Chart API

```
  def generate_qr_image( url )
    raw "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=#{url}&choe=UTF-8"
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Google changed the api end point.

This worked for me:

`= image_tag "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=#{url}&choe=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with TrAvid but it won't work, just need a small minute change,

Just assign `@url="www.google.com"`  in the controller and then use this `@url` in View as

```
<%= image_tag "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=#{@url}&choe=UTF-8" %>
```

It worked for me great.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, anything based on google charts is deprecated, so not a long term solution.

I've used both the rqrcode gem and one of the many javascript encoders.

Answer (score 0):

I use the rqrcode_png that allow you to save the code as an image or do it like a table. It also let you display the image without saving it.

Here is an example of how save the image

```
    qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new( 'your string', :size => 1, :level => :h )
    image = qr.to_img.resize(250,250)
    image.save('name.png')
```

or if you don't want to save it you can

```
     qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new( 'your string', :size => 1, :level => :h )
     @png = qr.to_img.resize(250,250).to_data_url
```

and then in your view `<%= image_tag @png %>`